# "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

This is a simple "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game I made in Python 3. Feel free to critique me and give suggestions on how can I improve my newbie coding skills.

```
import os
from random import randint


def ask_player():
    while True:
        print("Rock, paper or scissors?")
        ans = input(">")
        if ans in ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'):
            return ans


def results_msg(x, y, result):
    message = f"{x} beats {y}. You {result}!"
    return message


def comp_play():
    comp_choice = randint(0, 2)
    if comp_choice == 0:
        comp_choice = 'Rock'
    elif comp_choice == 1:
        comp_choice = 'Paper'
    else:
        comp_choice = 'Scissors'
    return comp_choice


def results(wins, losses, draws):
    player_choice = ask_player()
    comp_choice = comp_play()
    if player_choice == comp_choice:
        print("Draw. Nobody wins or losses.")
        draws += 1
    elif player_choice == 'Rock':
        if comp_choice == 'Paper':
            print(results_msg(comp_choice, player_choice, 'lost'))
            losses += 1
        else:
            print(results_msg(player_choice, comp_choice, 'won'))
            wins += 1
    elif player_choice == 'Paper':
        if comp_choice == 'Rock':
            print(results_msg(player_choice, comp_choice, 'won'))
            wins += 1
        else:
            print(results_msg(comp_choice, player_choice, 'lost'))
            losses += 1
    else:
        if comp_choice == 'Rock':
            print(results_msg(comp_choice, player_choice, 'lost'))
            losses += 1
        else:
            print(results_msg(player_choice, comp_choice, 'won'))
            wins += 1
    return wins, losses, draws


def play_again():
    while True:
        print("\nDo you want to play again?")
        print("[1] Yes")
        print("[2] No")
        ans = input("> ")
        if ans in '12':
            return ans


def main():
    wins = 0
    losses = 0
    draws = 0
    while True:
        os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
        print(f"Wins: {wins}\nLosses: {losses}\nDraws: {draws}")
        wins, losses, draws = results(wins, losses, draws)
        if play_again() == '2':
            break


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The follow-up is "*["Rock, Paper, Scissors" game - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215367/rock-paper-scissors-game-follow-up)*".

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Mast I apologize.

Comment: Don't worry, many people don't know the specific rules of Code Review and luckily we got a system in place that catches most of the trouble. You're still quite welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome back! There are a lot of good things to say about your program, and a few not-so-good. First, the good:

1. The code is clean, well laid-out, and generally written in a Pythonic style.
2. You have used functions to break things down.
3. You have structured your program as a module, which should make it easier to test.

Here are some things that I think could be improved:

1. Your function names need a little work. Consider this code:

   ```
   player_choice = ask_player()
   comp_choice = comp_play()
   ```

   The object is to get two choices, one made by the player and the other made by the computer. Why are the two names so different? `ask_player` doesn't sound like getting a player's choice. It sounds like a generalized function that asks the player something and gets a response (i.e., `input()`). On the other hand, if `player` is spelled out why do you abbreviate the opponent in `comp_play`?

   Using `get` is not always a good thing. It's one of the times when a function or method name doesn't need a verb in it - because it is frequently implicit when you are doing `is_...` or `has_...` or `get_...` or `set_...`. I don't think you need to spell out `get_player_choice` and `get_computer_choice`, but certainly `player_choice` and `computer_choice` would be appropriate.

This same logic applies to `results`. Instead of calling a function named `results`, why not call `play_once`? Or `one_game`? It's obvious from the code in `main` what is going on, but the function name doesn't really match the nature of the "step" being executed.

2. Your code breakdown is uneven. Consider this code:

   ```
   def main():
       wins = 0
       losses = 0
       draws = 0
       while True:
           os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
           print(f"Wins: {wins}\nLosses: {losses}\nDraws: {draws}")
           wins, losses, draws = results(wins, losses, draws)
           if play_again() == '2':
               break
   ```

   Let's break those lines down. The key point I want to make is to **keep neighboring statements at a similar level of abstraction.**

   First, you initialize your variables:

   ```
   wins = 0
   losses = 0
   draws = 0
   ```

   Because you are not using a class, and are not using globals (which would be appropriate in this scenario, IMO), you are stuck with doing variable initialization here. I suggest that you make this consistent with how you update the variables after each game:

   ```
   wins, losses, draws = starting_scores()
   ```

   Now, `starting_scores` could just `return 0,0,0` or it could load from a saved-game file. But it makes the initialization sufficiently abstract, and it also spells out what you are doing.

   Next, you loop:

   ```
   while True:
       ...
       if play_again() == '2':
           break
   ```

   The `while True ... break` could be rewritten to use a boolean variable. That's not super-critical, since the value of that variable is determined at only a single location. I consider the break to be equivalent in this case.

   *However,* the comparison `== '2'` is not acceptable! Why? Because that's a detail, and your function name `play_again` *should take care of that detail for you!* Don't ask a question and then interpret the answer. Make your question-asking code handle the interpretation for you. Obviously `play_again` is short for "do you want to play again?" and `'2'` is not a valid answer. `True` or `False` are valid answers, so the code should look like:

   ```
   while True:
       ...
       if not play_again():
           break
   ```

   Finally, the inside of your loop has the same problem:

   ```
   os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
   print(f"Wins: {wins}\nLosses: {losses}\nDraws: {draws}")
   wins, losses, draws = results(wins, losses, draws)
   ```

   What are you doing here? Well, you are clearing the screen, showing a summary of the games played, and playing one more round of the game. So say that!

   ```
   clear_screen()
   show_statistics(wins, losses, draws)
   wins, losses, draws = play_one_round(wins, losses, draws)
   ```
3. Use appropriate data structures.

   Your `main` code passes three variables to your play-game code. That code then returns three data items in a tuple, which you unpack into three variables.

   In fact, you never use one of those variables without also having the others at hand. This should tell you that you are dealing with one aggregate data item, instead of three independent pieces of data. If that's true, just treat the scores as a single item:

   ```
   def main():
       scores = starting_scores()

       while True:
           clear_screen()
           show_statistics(scores)
           scores = rock_paper_scissors(scores)

           if not play_again():
               break
   ```

   Similarly, you can treat the scores as an aggregate until you have to update them:

   ```
   # NB: was `results(wins, losses, draws):`
   def rock_paper_scissors(scores):
       player = player_choice()
       computer = computer_choice()
       outcome = game_outcome(player, computer)
       show_results(outcome, player, computer)
       new_scores = update_scores(scores, outcome)
       return new_scores
   ```

   At this point, the "play one game" has also become a collection of abstract statements. But notice that I'm treating `scores` as an opaque blob that I don't need to deal with: I just pass it along to the lower levels, with another data item describing the update to make.
4. Be consistent!

   I notice that when asking the player to choose rock, paper, or scissors, you allow them to type in an answer. But given a Yes/No question, you require a selection of either `1` or `2`. That's consistently surprising. When I ran your code, I wanted to keep typing my answers. (I kept hitting 'y' to play again.)

   I suggest you either present the Rock/Paper/Scissors options as a menu, or present the Yes/No options as a string input and look for 'y' or 'n'. Making the interface that much more consistent will be an improvement.
5. Use data, or code. Not both.

   This one is a little subtle, but take a look:

   ```
   if comp_choice == 'Paper':
       print(results_msg(comp_choice, player_choice, 'lost'))
       losses += 1
   else:
       print(results_msg(player_choice, comp_choice, 'won'))
       wins += 1
   ```

   What's significant here is that you have an `if/then` statement that decides whether you won or lost. And then you pass that into your `results_msg` function as a string parameter. The result of this is that you have a string parameter to be substituted that gives information you already knew: whether the player won or lost.

   Let's look at `results_msg`:

   ```
   def results_msg(x, y, result):
       message = f"{x} beats {y}. You {result}!"
       return message
   ```

   You have to consider that Python f-strings are code. And they're a pretty compact form of code, compared to the horror of *str.*`format()`. So writing:

   ```
   print(results_msg(player_choice, comp_choice, 'won'))
   ```

   is not really an improvement on writing:

   ```
   print(f"{player} beats {computer}. You won!")
   ```

   It's not clearer. It's not shorter. It *does* avoid problems with changing the text of the message, although there isn't much text in the message to change.

   I don't think you need to hoist the f-string up into the calling function. I *do* think you should not pass 'won' or 'lost' as a parameter: you already decided you won or lost. Call a separate function instead.

   ```
   if ...
       win_message(player_choice, comp_choice)
   else:
       lose_message(player_choice, comp_choice)
   ```

   Note that this will appear to conflict with the code structure I showed above- because in that code structure, I chose to treat the result as data, not code. I'm not saying you have to use data, or that you have to use code. I'm saying that you should pick one and stick with it. If you determine your outcome as code, go ahead and hard-code the outcome. If you determine your outcome as data, go ahead and treat it as data.

   And as a side note, strings with substitutions in them make it hard to do i18n. So there's nothing wrong with having an array of totally spelled out messages at the bottom. It also gives a bit more "flavor" if you customize the verbs:

   ```
   "Rock breaks scissors. You won!",
   "Scissors cuts paper. You won!",
   "Paper covers rock. You won!",
   ...
   ```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your very detailed answer. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hey again! I did almost everything you told me except that I can't understand how am I supposed to make game_outcome(), show_results() and update_scores() (they are called in rock_paper_scissors()).

Comment: As I wrote it, `game_outcome(a,b)` would compare two choices, and return a result that indicated the outcome of the game. Could be a number, could be a string, could be anything that works. Similarly, `show_results()` would take the outcome and the two choices and generate some kind of results display for the user. Printing a message would be appropriate. Finally, `update_scores()` should take the old scores object and return a new scores object with updated information.

Answer (score 3):

Just a real fast suggestion before I go to bed.
When doing the check for what type of action the player is doing set there input to lowercase so they dont have to get the case correct.

Example

```
if player_choice.lower() == 'paper':
```

In this example the code will run the `paper` logic if the player inputted `Paper` or `paper`

Answer (score 1):

In `comp_play`, you should return immediately instead of setting a variable to return at the end (although this is slightly controversial). However, you should replace your `random.randint`/`if`/`elif`/`else` with `random.choice`:

```py
def comp_play():
    return choice(('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'))
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you, that helped me get rid of some lines.