# "Rock, Paper, Scissors" game - follow-up

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, rock-paper-scissors

This is a follow-up to "*["Rock, Paper, Scissors" game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/215280/rock-paper-scissors-game)*". I did almost everything the answers recommended and I hope you like it.

```
import os
from random import choice


def player_choice():
    while True:
        print("Rock, paper or scissors?")
        choice = input(">").capitalize()
        if choice in ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'):
            return choice


def win_msg(player_choice, computer_choice):
    msg = f"{player_choice} beats {computer_choice}. You won!"
    return msg


def lose_msg(player_choice, computer_choice):
    msg = f"{computer_choice} beats {player_choice}. You lost!"
    return msg


def computer_choice():
    return choice(('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'))


def show_statistics(scores):
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
    print(f"Wins: {scores[0]}\nLosses: {scores[1]}\nDraws: {scores[2]}")


def game_outcome(player, computer):
    if player == computer:
        return 'Draw'
    elif player == 'Rock':
        if computer == 'Paper':
            return 'Lose'
        else:
            return 'Win'
    elif player == 'Paper':
        if computer == 'Rock':
            return 'Win'
        else:
            return 'Lose'
    else:
        if computer == 'Rock':
            return 'Lose'
        else:
            return 'Win'


def show_results(outcome, player, computer):
    if outcome == 'Win':
        print(win_msg(player, computer))
    elif outcome == 'Lose':
        print(lose_msg(player, computer))
    else:
        print("Draw. Nobody wins or losses.")


def update_scores(scores, outcome):
    new_scores = list(scores)
    if outcome == 'Win':
        new_scores[0] += 1
    elif outcome == 'Lose':
        new_scores[1] += 1
    else:
        new_scores[2] += 1
    new_scores = tuple(new_scores)
    return new_scores


def rock_paper_scissors(scores):
    player = player_choice()
    computer = computer_choice()
    outcome = game_outcome(player, computer)
    show_results(outcome, player, computer)
    new_scores = update_scores(scores, outcome)
    return new_scores


def play_again():
    while True:
        print("\nDo you want to play again?")
        print("(Y)es")
        print("(N)o")
        ans = input("> ").lower()
        if ans == 'y':
            return True
        elif ans == 'n':
            return False


def starting_scores():
    return 0, 0, 0


def main():
    scores = starting_scores()
    still_playing = True
    while still_playing:
        show_statistics(scores)
        scores = rock_paper_scissors(scores)
        still_playing = play_again()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, this is some nice clean code. Well done.

The changes I'd make:

1. `win_msg` and `lose_msg` can instead be global constant strings.
2. You should pick a preferred string delimiter and stick to using just that one. I prefer `'`.
3. I would make a function `clear_console` as the code is rather strange. And will ease use if you need it again.
4. `game_outcome` can be simplified by using a dictionary to store what beats what.

   This also means you can expand to RPSLS with ease.
5. `show_results` can be changed to use a dictionary too.
6. `update_scores` can be changed in one of two ways:

   - Add a dictionary that converts from `outcome` to the index.
   - Change `scores` to a dictionary.

And so you can get the following code:

```
import os
from random import choice

MESSAGES = {
    'Win': '{player} beats {computer}. You won!',
    'Lose': '{computer} beats {player}. You lost!',
    'Draw': 'Draw. Nobody wins or losses.'
}

BEATS = {
    'Rock': 'Scissors',
    'Paper': 'Rock',
    'Scissors': 'Paper'
}


def player_choice():
    while True:
        print('Rock, paper or scissors?')
        choice = input('>').capitalize()
        if choice in ('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'):
            return choice


def play_again():
    while True:
        print('\nDo you want to play again?')
        print('(Y)es')
        print('(N)o')
        ans = input('> ').lower()
        if ans == 'y':
            return True
        elif ans == 'n':
            return False


def computer_choice():
    return choice(('Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'))


def clear_console():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')


def game_outcome(player, computer):
    if player == computer:
        return 'Draw'

    if BEATS[player] == computer:
        return 'Win'
    else:
        return 'Lose'


def rock_paper_scissors(scores):
    clear_console()
    print(f'Wins: {scores["Win"]}\nLosses: {scores["Lose"]}\nDraws: {scores["Draw"]}')
    player = player_choice()
    computer = computer_choice()
    outcome = game_outcome(player, computer)
    print(MESSAGES[outcome].format(player=player, computer=computer))
    scores[outcome] += 1
    return new_scores


def main():
    scores = {
        'Win': 0,
        'Lose': 0,
        'Draw': 0
    }
    still_playing = True
    while still_playing:
        scores = rock_paper_scissors(scores)
        still_playing = play_again()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

From here you can look into using [`enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) to remove the strings from your code. This is good because it's easy to make a typo in a string, say I use `'rock'` rather than `'Rock'`. It also means that if you do make a typo then you'll be able to see where it was made when you reach that code. However with a string it'll move the error to a later part of the code and make debugging horrible.

Here is an example of how you can use them:

```
from enum import Enum


class Score(Enum):
    WIN = 'Win'
    LOSE = 'Lose'
    DRAW = 'Draw'


MESSAGES = {
    Score.WIN: '{player} beats {computer}. You won!',
    Score.LOSE: '{computer} beats {player}. You lost!',
    Score.DRAW: 'Draw. Nobody wins or losses.'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) that you can use a `dict`, but I would not use it this way. Not because it won't work but because it only works in this specific case.

```
WIN = {('paper', 'rock'), ('rock', 'scissors'), ('scissors', 'paper')}

def game_outcome(player, computer):
    if player==computer:
        print('Draw. Nobody wins or losses.')
        return 0
    elif (player, computer) in WIN:
        print(f'{player} beats {computer}. You won!')
        return 1
    elif (computer, player) in WIN:
        print(f'{computer} beats {player}. You lost!')
        return -1  
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"no defined rule for '{player}' and '{computer}'")
```

```
>>> game_outcome('paper', 'paper')
Draw. Nobody wins or looses.
0
>>> game_outcome('rock', 'paper')
paper beats rock. You lost!
-1
>>> game_outcome('paper', 'rock')
paper beats rock. You won!
1
```

Why is it more generic, because if you want to play [**rock-paper-scissor-lizard-spock**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x5Q6-wMx-K8), you just change the dict to this:

```
RULES = {
    ('paper', 'rock'): 'covers',
    ('rock', 'scissors'): 'crushes',
    ('rock', 'lizard'): 'crushes',
    ('spock', 'rock'): 'vaporises',
    ('scissors', 'paper'): 'cuts',
    ('lizard', 'paper'): 'eats',
    ('paper', 'spock'): 'disproves',
    ('scissors', 'lizard'): 'decapitates',
    ('spock', 'scissors'): 'smashes',
    ('lizard', 'spock'): 'poisons'
}
def game_outcome(player, computer):
    if player==computer:
        print('Draw. Nobody wins or losses.')
        return 0
    elif (player, computer) in RULES:
        print(f'{player} {RULES[player, computer]} {computer}. You won!')
        return 1
    elif (computer, player) in RULES:
        print(f'{computer} {RULES[computer, player]} {player}. You lost!')
        return -1  
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(f"no defined rule for '{player}' and '{computer}'")
```

```
>>> game_outcome('paper', 'spock')
paper disproves spock. You won!
1
>>> game_outcome('lizard', 'spock')
lizard poisons spock. You won!
1
>>> game_outcome('lizard', 'scissor')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 12, in game_outcome
NotImplementedError: no defined rule for 'lizard' and 'scissor'
>>> game_outcome('lizard', 'scissors')
scissors decapitates lizard. You lost!
-1
```

All this code just to say that `{(inputs, ...): output}` is generally a good pattern when the mapping between the inputs and the output isn't obvious.

Comment: I find it funny how you say "don't use a dict" and use a dict in your second code.

Comment: **"I agree with Peilonrayz that you can use a dict, but I would not use it this way"** You probably misread. (and I didn't edit anything)